# Merge two array of object and sort on the value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, merge

```js
const a=[{id:1},{id:5},{id:7},{id:6}]
const b=[{id:7},{id:2},{id:5},{id:9}]

//Merge and sort in single array of object based on unique value
```

Expected Output:
[{id:1},{id:2},{id:5},{id:6},{id:7},{id:9}]

Tried merging first and sorting not able to get desired result
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`Map Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

```js
const a = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 5 }, { id: 7 }, { id: 6 }];
const b = [{ id: 7 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 5 }, { id: 9 }];
const map = new Map();
a.forEach((x) => map.set(x.id, { ...x }));
b.forEach((x) => map.set(x.id, { ...x }));
const ret = [...map.values()].sort((x, y) => x.id - y.id);
console.log(ret);
```

Another solution using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

```js
const a = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 5 }, { id: 7 }, { id: 6 }];
const b = [{ id: 7 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 5 }, { id: 9 }];
const ret = Object.values(
  [...a, ...b].reduce((prev, c) => {
    const p = prev;
    const key = c.id;
    p[key] = { ...c };
    return p;
  }, {})
);
console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have `id` only in the range of positive 32 bit integers, you could take an object and get a sorted result.

```js
const
    a = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 5 }, { id: 7 }, { id: 6 }],
    b = [{ id: 7 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 5 }, { id: 9 }],
    merged = Object.values([...a, ...b].reduce((r, o) => (r[o.id] = o, r), {}));


console.log(merged);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: in learning ... could you please explain what inside of reduce does here  ?

Comment: @Codenewbie, it take a compound ecxpression with an assignment to a hash table and separated by comma operator, it returns the object/hash table. the hash table is the accumulator of `reduces` and the inherend ordering of the keys of objects assure the order.

Answer (score 1):

You could get your desired output by combining [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), like this:

```js
const a = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 5 }, { id: 7 }, { id: 6 }];
const b = [{ id: 7 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 5 }, { id: 9 }];

// Combine the two arrays by using the spread operator
const c = [...a, ...b].reduce((acc, curr) => {
  // Check if the value is already present in the array
  const isPresentInArray = acc.some((x) => x.id === curr.id);

  if (!isPresentInArray) {
    acc.push(curr);
  }

  return acc;
}, []).sort((l, r) => l.id - r.id);

console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `set` (to track the unique items), `filter` and `sort`.

```js
const mergeSortUnique = (arrA, arrB) => {
  const set = new Set();
  return [...arrA, ...arrB]
    .filter(({ id }) => ((res = !set.has(id)), set.add(id), res))
    .sort(({ id: a }, { id: b }) => a - b);
};

const a = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 5 }, { id: 7 }, { id: 6 }];
const b = [{ id: 7 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 5 }, { id: 9 }];

console.log(mergeSortUnique(a, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest version i can come with is :

```js
const a=[{id:1},{id:5},{id:7},{id:6}];
const b=[{id:7},{id:2},{id:5},{id:9}];

const result = [...a, ...b]
.filter((v,i,k)=>k.findIndex(t=>(t.id === v.id)) === i)
.sort((x,u)=>x.id - u.id);

console.log(result);
```